# Text shortcuts reset to older settings in System Preferences

Tags: keyboard, icloud, shortcut, preferences

I use the **Text shortcuts replace** function provided by Mac OS X's *System Preferences' Keyboard* panel quite often. It helps me type things faster in most applications, such as my phone number, my full address, etc.

Lately, I've noticed that the text fields that I have recently updated got deleted/replaced by older values (maybe it's synchronized with a Cloud backup?). It's not the first time it does that.

This is what I have in **situation 1** (correct information):

[image]

And after a few days when I'll use one of these shortcuts, I'll find that they have been replaced to previous info. **Situation 2** presents old info as such:

[image]

So I have to go back to Keyboard preferences, and re-type my current information where needed each time.

Where is this old info coming from? Another Cloud-linked device? Since this happens on a computer connected to the internet, why won't the info update on all devices when I edit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they cross-pollinate from other devices. Mine come from my phone.

I'm really not certain why they don't correctly sync both ways. If I add one to the Mac it appears on the phone, but ones deleted from the Mac don't necessarily delete from the phone & may later re-appear on the Mac.

I've found the best solution is to just make sure you've also deleted them from any other device.
Settings > General > Keyboards > Text Replacement